# Navigation bar not visible on new contact page

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to show new contact page on button click I have written this code within action button

```
{  
    ABNewPersonViewController *abnewpersonviewcontroller = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];   
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:abnewpersonviewcontroller animated:YES];
    [newPersonController release];
 }
```

this code succesfully reach me to the new contact page but the problem is navigation bar not shown onto the new contact page in which i can save record and also have cancel button on it kindly tell me how I can display the navigation on new contact page when I click on action button

Comment: how did u add the navigation bar in the first place ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use this

```
ABNewPersonViewController *abnewpersonviewcontroller = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init]; 
self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:abnewpersonviewcontroller animated:YES];
[newPersonController release];
```

Comment: it is added but now the problem is when i save record or click on cancel but it not disappear new contact viewcontroller

Comment: add this line self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES; in your viewController viewWillAppear method when selecting or cancelling and going to your viewController where you pushed that ABNewPersonViewController

Answer (score 1):

```
    ABNewPersonViewController *picker =[ABNewPersonViewController new];
    UINavigationController *nc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:picker];
    picker.newPersonViewDelegate =self;
    [self presentViewController:nc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can add `self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = NO;` to that pushed view controller in `- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated` method to force it but it should show automatically if you didn't added extra `UINavigationBar` to your `UINavigationController`.

Comment: it show me this error property visible not found on object of type uinavigationbar

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I have edited answer. But to me it seems that you have added another `UINavigationBar` and that's the reason why you have this problem, because obviously one is over another one and doesn't respect navigation controller stack.

Answer (score 0):

did you hide navigation bar in your application?

if yes, then you should unhide before moving to contact page........

thanks